# Calling Javascript function from along with json

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, json, android-webview

Hi all i am calling a javascript function on `WebView` in android. I am sending a `JSON` data which will pass value to html.
My `JSON` data is in following format i have checked using online tools it is valid.

```
{"Results":{"Number of Tests":"2","Latency(avg)":"17","Failure":"0%","Latitude":"12° 55' 35.5872''  N","Longitude":"77° 36' 4.16916''  E","Latency(max)":"18","Latency(min)":"17"},"TestStaus":"Passed","Test":"Game Test"}
```

I am using following code to display parsed result in html using jquery.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(vk);
document.write(jsonObject); 
$.each($.parseJSON(jsonObject), function(k, v)
{
     document.write("<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v + "</td></tr>");
 });
```

It is giving me output in following manner

1. Parameter        Value
2. Results          [object Object]
3. TestStatus       Passed
4. Test             Game Test

Please help how to read all results. Why it is reading object object.

Comment: What is the problem? "document.write(jsonObject);" output "Object"? This is normal since jsonObject hasn't method toString().

Comment: Use `console.log(k)` and view in the console. You can't document.write a  json object. It's too complex to just be added to the page like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use recursion. You need to be able to handle multidimensional objects. Also, I usually use jquery for DOM or AJAX only. For something like this, you might not need it.

Your Json

```
   var vk = {"Results":{
     "Number of Tests":"2",
     "Latency(avg)":"17",
     "Failure":"0%",
     "Latitude":"12° 55' 35.5872''  N",
     "Longitude":"77° 36' 4.16916'' E","Latency(max)":"18",
     "Latency(min)":"17"
      },
     "TestStaus":"Passed",
     "Test":"Game Test"};
```

Recursive function

```
     function drawJSON(obj){
      for(var key in obj){
      if(typeof obj[key] === 'object'){
       drawJSON(obj[key]);
       continue;
      }
      document.write("<div><span>" + key + "</span><span>" + obj[key] + "</span> </div>");
      }
    }

    drawJSON(vk);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ikuDagE/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

The Results is object so it is showing as [object object]. You can do this by:

```
   function printEach(jsonObject) {
        $.each(jsonObject, function(k, v)
        {
            if(typeof v === 'object') {
                printEach(v);
            } else {
                console.log("<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v + "</td></tr>");
            }        
        });
    }

    var vk = {"Results":{"Number of Tests":"2","Latency(avg)":"17","Failure":"0%","Latitude":"12° 55' 35.5872''  N","Longitude":"77° 36' 4.16916''  E","Latency(max)":"18","Latency(min)":"17"},"TestStaus":"Passed","Test":"Game Test"};
    var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(vk); 
    printEach($.parseJSON(jsonObject));
```

You can see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/58grs/1/